# Access and modify extern variable in MongoDB request

Tags: node.js, node-mongodb-native

I have a problem in a nodeJS app with mongoDB, i'm trying to do a forum and for each topic i want a button to display every sub topics.
So i need to get everything in the request:

> - One array with main topics
> - Another map array with ['topic1'] containing sub topics

Without the mapping (not an actual problem) i have this:

```
    Post.find({'path': path})
    .exec(function (err, posts){
    if(err)
        console.log("Get post list:" + err);
    else
    {
            var sub_posts = new Array; // Second array with sub topics
            for (var i = 0; posts[i]; i++) //Here is the loop for each topic
            {
                var tmp_path = ... // Path and next request works
                Post.find({'path': tmp_path}) // Here is the second request
                .exec(function(err, bis_posts) {
                    if (err) console.log('Error loading subforum');
                    else sub_posts.push(bis_posts); // Affectation fail !!! 
                })
            }
            res.render(... 'post_list': posts, 'sub_posts': sub_posts); // Send result
    }
})}
```

So i get it's a scope problem and i should use callback but with the loop i can't resolve this problem.

Sorry for my english and thanks for your answers !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what you mean by "affectation fail", but it looks like you're calling `res.render` too early — callbacks are invoked *asynchronously after your current context finishes executing*, so when you call `res.render(...)` after your `for` loop has finished, your `Post.find(...)...` operations still haven't finished and their callbacks haven't been invoked, so `sub_posts` will be still empty.

My node.js and Mongo are rusty, so perhaps this isn't the canonical way to do it, but I'd add a counter to track the state of the pending requests and only call `res.render` when all subposts have been fetched:

```
var sub_posts = new Array;
var pending = 0;
for (var i = 0; posts[i]; i++)
{
    var tmp_path = ...
    Post.find({'path': tmp_path})
    .exec(function(err, bis_posts) {
        if (err) console.log('Error loading subforum');
        else sub_posts.push(bis_posts);
        pending -= 1;
        if (!pending) {
            // all pending subpost lookups finished, render the response:
            res.render(... 'post_list': posts, 'sub_posts': sub_posts);
        }
    });
    pending += 1;
}
```

Comment: Affectation didn't failed but i couldn't get sub_post then. But i understand the logic now, thanks for the answer !